# Pandas Time series: find gaps in sessions, and name each session/gap with separate ID

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, time-series

I am struggling with an obviously simple task and hope to find some help here!

I have something like the following DataFrame.

```
d = [
['2021-06-01 08:00:00',"A"],
['2021-06-01 09:00:00',"A"],
['2021-06-01 12:00:00',"B"],
['2021-06-01 13:00:00',"B"],
['2021-06-01 18:00:00',"B"],
['2021-06-01 19:00:00',"B"],
['2021-06-01 22:00:00',"C"],
['2021-06-01 23:00:00',"C"]] 

df=pd.DataFrame(data=d, columns=("timestamp", "session"))
```

I want to identify time gaps greater than a threshold (e.g. 1h) **within** a session. time gaps between sessions shall not be considered 
for this purpose, I used the *.diff()* method to locate the gaps.

```
df["timestamp"]= pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"])

df["gap"]=df["timestamp"].diff().dt.seconds > 3600
```

the **main task** is to find a gap within a session and cut the session into pieces by **renaming** the parts/sessions with e.g. `uuid.uuid4()`.
in the example, it would lead to new session names in row 5/6.

my approach was a for-iteration over the unique sessions, but I am not able to rename the parts, when I find a *True* in the "gap" column.
I would like to stay in the "pandas world" since this is a big data task.

Comment: Could you provide an example of expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

1. Modify your logics to setup column `gap` to group under `session` by using [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)
2. Use [`GroupBy.cumsum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html) to get the `group` id (new session name) within same session **(separate `group` id for each time gap larger than 1 hour)**
3. Use [`GroupBy.transform()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) to generate the uuid for each group (different uuid for each session and separate uuid for each gap within the same session)

```
import uuid

# Keep your existing codes:
df["timestamp"]= pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"])

# Modify your existing codes:
#df["gap"] = df["timestamp"].diff().dt.seconds > 3600
df["gap"] = df.groupby('session')["timestamp"].diff().dt.seconds > 3600

# New codes:
df['group'] = df.groupby('session')['gap'].cumsum()
df['session_gap_id'] = df.groupby(['session', 'group'], as_index=False)['group'].transform(lambda x: uuid.uuid4())
```

**Result:**

Here, there are **different session names `session_gap_id` for each `session` and also separate `session_gap_id` for each different group within a session, including row 5/6 (row index 4/5)**

```
print(df)

            timestamp session    gap  group                        session_gap_id
0 2021-06-01 08:00:00       A  False      0  3cca414b-6bbf-4474-92c4-a0c8273955d8
1 2021-06-01 09:00:00       A  False      0  3cca414b-6bbf-4474-92c4-a0c8273955d8
2 2021-06-01 12:00:00       B  False      0  9c86305e-fcd6-42c8-b532-39d342a3b35c
3 2021-06-01 13:00:00       B  False      0  9c86305e-fcd6-42c8-b532-39d342a3b35c
4 2021-06-01 18:00:00       B   True      1  0dbcf66c-ce0d-4b01-93e2-978d77348235
5 2021-06-01 19:00:00       B  False      1  0dbcf66c-ce0d-4b01-93e2-978d77348235
6 2021-06-01 22:00:00       C  False      0  9b31532c-55c0-4a66-8719-1edbb9047fba
7 2021-06-01 23:00:00       C  False      0  9b31532c-55c0-4a66-8719-1edbb9047fba
```

Answer (score 0):

- you can use **groupby / transform** to identify gaps within sessions
- without a sample of your expected output it's not clear what you are looking to achieve with creating rows where there are gaps

```
d = [
['2021-06-01 08:00:00',"A"],
['2021-06-01 09:00:00',"A"],
['2021-06-01 12:00:00',"B"],
['2021-06-01 13:00:00',"B"],
['2021-06-01 18:00:00',"B"],
['2021-06-01 19:00:00',"B"],
['2021-06-01 22:00:00',"C"],
['2021-06-01 23:00:00',"C"]] 

df=pd.DataFrame(data=d, columns=("timestamp", "session"))
df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"])

df["gap"] = df.groupby("session")["timestamp"].transform(lambda s: s.shift(-1) > s+pd.Timedelta("1h"))
df
```

| timestamp | session | gap |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-06-01 08:00:00 | A | False |
| 2021-06-01 09:00:00 | A | False |
| 2021-06-01 12:00:00 | B | False |
| 2021-06-01 13:00:00 | B | True |
| 2021-06-01 18:00:00 | B | False |
| 2021-06-01 19:00:00 | B | False |
| 2021-06-01 22:00:00 | C | False |
| 2021-06-01 23:00:00 | C | False |